# Is there any way of accessing Firefox errors' list in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firebug

I am wondering whether I can somehow access list of all errors in Firefox with Firebug installed. I was trying to find some variable that stores it or read data from Firebug console. Unfortunately, with no luck. Is it possible? If so, could you please give me some hint?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have a look at http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/category/firebug/

Comment: I am not saying I want to capture full content of Firebug console. I just need errors list which is displayed in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the [Firebug Console API](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API) doesn't include any way to retrieve information from the console, it only has methods for pushing information into the console.